# ElementClickInterceptedException:

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, python

```
CONSOLE ERROR :
 Message: element click intercepted: Element <div class="button" data-target="false" data-id="2">..</div> is not clickable at point (937, 293). Other element would receive the click: <body data-anm=".anm" class="">...</body>   (Session info: chrome=88.0.4324.104)

I am clicking on the button but when I come to the button it did not click on it and showing an error.
I have also change it by XPath css but not working.
am facing this problem in selenium python 

WEBSITE URL:
                https://aujtravels.com/breeo-canada/register
```

script :

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://aujtravels.com/breeo-canada/register")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//h4[contains(text(),'Student')]").click()
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@data-id='1']").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("first_name").send_keys("a")
driver.find_element_by_id("last_name").send_keys("b")
driver.find_element_by_id("email").send_keys("hr@gmail.com")
time.sleep(2)
driver.execute_script(" window.scrollBy(0, 350);")
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div[data-id='2']").click()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### There is a bug in that page , the next button is not fully displayed as footer is overlapping half of it . you can click using javascript if you are not using it to test something. THe code is as below , you have to do it for second next buttton also

```
next = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@data-id='1']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()",next)
```

Comment: it works fine thanks

Comment: please accept by clicking the tick sign near to the answer and also upvote:)